# How to listen for a paste event on a form in Safari with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, safari

I have a form in Vuejs. On the input for a credit card number, I have this:
`@change="updateNumber($event)"`

In Chrome, when I paste a credit card number, or one is autofilled from my saved cards, this is recognized as a "change". However, that isn't the case in Safari. A change event isn't emitted. I'm wondering which event I need to listen for and how to set that custom event listener in my Vuejs component. Thank you!

Comment: The `input` event catches pastes

Comment: For those who have this problem too, the paste event isn't emitted either. I have only seen the input event work in Safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of listening for `@change` listen for `@input` which will trigger an event when a user pastes into the input.

Your final code becomes:

```
@input="updateNumber($event)"
```

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/6wrxvuLg/) that I tested in both Chrome and Safari